# Overriding amended time stamps

Tags: shell, scripting, rename

I need to make it so the files in current directory get amended with a timestamp. It works fine for the first time, but once I run it again it adds another timestamp to the file. I need a way to replace the timestamp, not just add to it.

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS='
'

time=$(date)

for file in *
do
     mv $file "$file""$time"
done
```

I'm trying to think of how to overwrite the old files, but because the name changes when it gets amended with the timestamp I can't think of a way.

Comment: Did you try to debug to see why only works the first time?
You have a logic error there that you did not take into account. suggestion: put set -x before IFS and set +x after done. then run the script twice and you will understand why it's adding timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to replace the current portion of the date in the file's name and then replace it. This is a straight string manipulation activity to parse out the base name portion of the file's name. Without more information as to the current naming convention a solution can't really be provided beyond a general approach as to what to do.

#### Example

Assuming files are named **blah_..date..**

```
for file in *
do

  basefile=${file/_*//}
  mv "$file" "$basefile""$time"
done
```

This will chop off anything after the `_`, and store it in `$basefile`.

#### Names

```
$ echo "$file"
blah_Sun Oct 27 15:20:58 EDT 2013

$ echo ${file/_*//}
blah/
```

Answer (score 0):

One way can be to keep the original file names in a file in the same directory and instead of reading the files in a for loop you can use the following while loop to read the file names and add the time stamp to the names:

```
while read file                                                                                                                                                                    
do                                                                                                                                                                                 
  mv $file$(date)                                                                                                                                                                  
done < "files.txt"
```

`files.txt` can be produced by `ls > files.txt` for example and you must run this command before running the actual script on the command line or a separate script and just once.